# Set focus in Outlook mailitem.To field using c#?

Tags: c#, outlook, focus, outlook-addin, setfocus

how to i set/change a cursor focus in outlook mailitem.To or Mailitem.Subject field using C#.

I already done to create a Addin using Outlook 2010 Addin C#.Now i have an issue to focus change in newmail To,CC,subject Field.

How can resolve this?

thanks 
Sanju

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Accessibility API for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dmitry...Can you give any examples or samples?

Comment: I don't have any examples that I can share, sorry.

Comment: Use inspect.exe from Windows SDK to look at the names and ids of various controls as seen by the Accessibility API.